# How do I close the picker for type="datetime-local"

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am using vue  and i have type="datetime-local". I am able to select the date and time but I want the picker to close after a time has been selected.

I have tried to add an on change but can't find the correct code that will close the picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `blur` method to close the picker when any time/date is selected.

Here is the demo-

```html
<html>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="datetime-local" id="td" name="td" @input="close()" />
  </div>
  <!-- Don't forget to include Vue from CDN! -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app', //Tells Vue to render in HTML element with id "app"
      methods: {
        close() {
          let el = document.getElementById("td");
          if (el) {
            el.blur();
          }
        },
      }
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Additionally, do you know of a way to only .blur() when the minutes are clicked?

Comment: I added a counter so every three clicks it'll close
                
let el = document.getElementById();
                this.clicks += 1
                if (el && this.clicks == 3) {
                    this.clicks = 0;
                    el.blur();
                }

Comment: Is it working? Well, I have two approaches in mind, not sure if useful. First is, to inspect the minute selector and add a listener to it which will close the picker. The second is, to check the input value every time select any date/time, and if only the minute is changed that means only minutes cliked, so close the picker. Let me know if I am clear.

Comment: Yes, your comment is clear, and it is working, thanks

Comment: Is there any solution other than vue? for example js or jquery?